# Return indexes of matchings between two lists

Tags: python, match

Let's suppose that I have the following lists:

```
input_1 = ['a', 'c', None, 'e']

input_2 = ['e', 'a', 'b', 'q', 'f']
```

I want to have the following list as output:

```
output = [1, None, None, 0]
```

The `output` should have the indices of `input_2` of the elements which match to the respective elements in `input_1`.

If an element is `None` in `input_1` then this should not match to anything but the `output` at the respective index/position should be directly `None`.

So if write the `output` in words then this would be:

```
output = [index of 'a' in input_2, no match for 'c' , (by definition) no match for None, index of 'e' in input_2]
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily is you create a mapping dict that would contain the elements of list `input_2` as keys and their positions as value

```
>>> mapping = {e:i for i,e in enumerate(input_2)}
>>> [mapping.get(e) for e in input_1]            
[1, None, None, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_1 = ['a', 'c', None, 'e']

input_2 = ['e', 'a', 'b', 'q']

output=[]
for x in input_1:
  if x in input_2:
    output.append(input_2.index(x))
  else:
    output.append(None)

print(output)
```

Comment: Could you add a bit of detail on what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best way. I have created a dict for input_2, then use that to get final result. overall complexity is O(n+m). In this way no need to find index for each item:

```
dataDict = {}
for index, value in enumerate(input_2):
    dataDict[value] = index
result = [dataDict[d] if d and d in input_2 else None for d in input_1]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

for completness;
generate *output* using a single liner, list comprehension

```
input_1 = ['a', 'c', None, 'e']
input_2 = ['e', 'a', 'b', 'q', 'f']

output = [
    input_2.index(x) if x in input_2 and x is not None else None
    for x
    in input_1
]

assert [1, None, None, 0] == output
```